# jquery function not being called by web api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have  an web api to post data in the table when data entered in html page through jquery.
The web api function is as:

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(User user)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.UserID }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

And the html page with jquery script is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    <h2>All users</h2>
    <ul id="users" />
  </div>

<div>
    <h2>Insert New User</h2>
    First Name : <input type="text" id="firstName"  /><br />
    Last Name : <input type="text" id="lastName"  /><br />
    City  : <input type="text" id="city"  /><br />
    Email : <input type="email" id="email"  /><br />
    Password : <input type="password" id="password"  /><br />
    Phone number:    <input type="number" id="phone"  /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="Post();" />
    <p id="P1" />
  </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      var uri = 'api/user';

      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Send an AJAX request
          getuserlist();
      });


      function getuserlist() {
          $.getJSON(uri)
             .done(function (data) {
                 $('#users').html('');
                 // On success, 'data' contains a list of users.
                 $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                     // Add a list item for the user.

                     $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#users'));
                 });
             });
      }
      function formatItem(item) {
          return 'email:' + item.email + ' and First Name:' + item.firstName + ' and Last Name: ' + item.lastName;
      }

      function Post() {
          jQuery.support.cors = true;
          var source = {
              'firstName': $('#firstName').val(),
              'lastName': $('#lastName').val(),
              'email': $('#email').val(),
              'phone': $('#phone').val(),
              'city': $('#city').val(),
              'password': $('#password').val()
          }
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "/api/user",
              data: source,
              success: function (data) {
                  var strResult = "<table><th>Returned Message</th>";
                  // $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                  strResult += "<tr><td> " + source.email + " </td></tr>"
                  strResult += "</table>";
                  $("#divResult").html(strResult);
              },
              error: function (x, y, z) {

                  var strResult = "<table><th>Error Message</th>";
                  // $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                  strResult += "<tr><td> " + x.responseText + " </td></tr>"
                  strResult += "</table>";
                  $("#divResult").html(strResult);
                  // alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
              }
              //success: function (data) {
              //    //alert(data);
              //    getuserlist();
              //    // alert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));

              //},
              //error: function (error) {
              //    jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
              //    //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
              //}
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I click on the button to add anew user,the post() function is not working.
the page remains the same,no action,no error.

please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Where's your post function ?

Comment: go down in the script tag

Comment: oops, sorry I didn't noticed that, Anyways can you please verify error in firebug/fiddler ?

Comment: And why did you enabled this `CORS` `jQuery.support.cors = true;`? are you going for a cross domain request?

Comment: Nothing is happening when i click the save button...yes I will need it later.

Comment: try remove that `cors=true` and issue still persist then post the actual error, you can find it in firebug or browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the url that you are posting to should be `"/api/user/Post"`.

**Output**

[image]

There are several other `JavaScript` errors in the posted code that I had to fix. As other's have mentioned in the comments these errors were shown in the console. Knowing how to debug using the developer tools is invaluable and worth investing time to learn them.

Here is the updated code fixed:

```
  <div>
    <h2>All users</h2>
    <ul id="users" />
  </div>

<div>
    <h2>Insert New User</h2>
    First Name : <input type="text" id="firstName"  /><br />
    Last Name : <input type="text" id="lastName"  /><br />
    City  : <input type="text" id="city"  /><br />
    Email : <input type="email" id="email"  /><br />
    Password : <input type="password" id="password"  /><br />
    Phone number:    <input type="number" id="phone"  /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnsave" value="Save" onclick="Post();" />
    <p id="P1" />
  </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     var uri = 'api/user';

      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Send an AJAX request
          getuserlist();
      });


      function getuserlist() {
          $.getJSON(uri)
             .done(function (data) {
                 $('#users').html('');
                 // On success, 'data' contains a list of users.
                 $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                     // Add a list item for the user.

                     $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#users'));
                 });
             });
      }
      function formatItem(item) {
          return 'email:' + item.email + ' and First Name:' + item.firstName + ' and Last Name: ' + item.lastName;
      }

      function Post() {
          jQuery.support.cors = true;
          var source = {
              'firstName': $('#firstName').val(),
              'lastName': $('#lastName').val(),
              'email': $('#email').val(),
              'phone': $('#phone').val(),
              'city': $('#city').val(),
              'password': $('#password').val()
          }
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "/api/user/Post",
              data: source,
              success: function (data) {
                  var strResult = "<table><th>Returned Message</th>";
                  $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                      strResult += "<tr><td> " + source.email + " </td></tr>"
                      strResult += "</table>";
                      $("#divResult").html(strResult);
                  });
              },
              error: function (x, y, z) {

                  var strResult = "<table><th>Error Message</th>";
                  $.each(x, function (index, data) {
                      strResult += "<tr><td> " + x.responseText + " </td></tr>"
                      strResult += "</table>";
                      $("#divResult").html(strResult);
                      // alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                  });
              }
              //success: function (data) {
              //    //alert(data);
              //    getuserlist();
              //    // alert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));

              //},
              //error: function (error) {
              //    jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
              //    //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
              //}
          });
      };
  </script>
```

I have also made the assumption that your `User` object is as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mine worked too.There were some validation exception that I have unhandled,that are meant to be handled.